# How to import .dta via pandas and describe data?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, import, error-handling, stata

I am new to python and have a simple problem. In a first step, I want to load some sample data I created in Stata. In a second step, I would like to describe the data in python - that is, I'd like a list of the imported variable names. So far I've done this:

```
from pandas.io.stata import StataReader

reader = StataReader('sample_data.dta')
data = reader.data()

dir()
```

I get the following error:

```
anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/stata.py:1375: UserWarning: 'data' is deprecated, use 'read' instead
  warnings.warn("'data' is deprecated, use 'read' instead")
```

What does it mean and how can I resolve the issue? And, is `dir()` the right way to get an understanding of what variables I have in the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`pandas.io.stata.StataReader.data`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.stata.StataReader.data.html) to read from a `stata` file has been deprecated in `pandas 0.18.1` version and hence you are getting that warning.

Instead, you must use [`pandas.read_stata`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_stata.html) to read the file as shown:

```
df = pd.read_stata('sample_data.dta')
df.dtypes                                        ## Return the dtypes in this object
```

Comment: Thanks I used `import pandas` and the command you suggested. However, df.dtyps does not return the data types. Any hints on why?

Comment: You must add a `print` statement before it.

Comment: Perfect, works! Thank you! I hope, I can now use the vars. Can I simple call the variables by their names or do I have to specify them first?

Comment: If you mean the columns, you could access them via `df['column name']`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this did not work for me especially when the dataset is large. So the thing I propose here is 2 steps (Stata and Python)

In Stata write the following commands:

```
export excel Cevdet.xlsx, firstrow(variables)
```

and to copy the variable labels write the following

```
describe, replace
    list
    export excel using myfile.xlsx, replace first(var)
restore
```

this will generate for you two files `Cevdet.xlsx` and `myfile.xlsx`

Now you go to your jupyter notebook

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_excel('Cevdet.xlsx')
```

This will allow you to read both files into jupyter (python 3)

My advice is to save this data file (especially if it is big)

```
df.to_pickle('Cevdet')
```

The next time you open jupyter you can simply run

```
df=pd.read_pickle("Cevdet")
```